# PHP select from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables, cross-join

I have 3 database tables: `site`, `paper` and `linkTable`.

```
 idSite     SiteName  
 --------------------
   1           AAA
   2           BBB
   3           CCC


idPaper     PaperName
------------------------
   1           Paper1
   2           Paper2
   3           Paper3
   4           Paper4


idLinkTable    idSite   idPaper
----------------------------------
     1           1         1
     2           1         3
     3           2         1
```

I want to show all the papers without `idPaper=1`,`idPaper=3` for `idSite=1`;
Similarly for `idSite=2`, need all the papers without `idPaper=1`. This is the required output:

```
SiteName  PaperName
------------------------
   AAA         Paper2
   AAA         Paper4
   BBB         Paper2
   BBB         Paper3
   BBB         Paper4
```

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT s.SiteName AS Site, p.PaperName AS Paper
 FROM site s 
INNER JOIN linkTable l ON s.idSite = l.idSite 
INNER JOIN paper p ON l.idPaper != p.idPaper;
```

This is my result when i am using this code:

```
SiteName  PaperName
------------------------
   AAA         Paper2
   AAA         Paper3
   AAA         Paper4
   AAA         Paper1
   AAA         Paper2
   AAA         Paper4
   BBB         Paper2
   BBB         Paper3
   BBB         Paper4
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @mitri Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/52168294/2469308 work for you ? You need all possible combinations, except the ones in `linkTable` already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need all possible combinations between `Site` and `Paper` tables, except the ones which already exist in the `linkTable`. Use [CROSS JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cross-join/) to get all possible combinations, and [NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) to eliminate the results already existing in the `linkTable`. Try the following:

```
SELECT s.SiteName AS Site, p.PaperName AS Paper
FROM site s 
CROSS JOIN paper p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT idLinkTable FROM linkTable 
                   WHERE linkTable.idSite = s.idSite 
                     AND linkTable.idPaper = p.idPaper
                 )
```